# Get images from Cache MAGENTO

Tags: php, image, magento, caching, magento-1.9

I have the following situation.

It pictures to nearly 10 megabytes and to perform the necessary routine can be up to 4 megabytes.

I can get the images as follows:

```
$imgsProdMagento = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($imgsProdMagento as $imgProdMagento) {
    var_dump($imgProdMagento);
}
```

It returns me the picture with 10 megabytes, looking at the frontend is possible to see the image qua cache is much smaller, as I do to obtain it?

I've tried as follows, however it returns me just an image that is marked and does not return me the URL.

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
```

I need to get the url of all images of the product starting from the cache.

Comment: Consider asking this on the official [Magento StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [Get full cached path of product relative images Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208350/get-full-cached-path-of-product-relative-images-magento)

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(2000);
```